# SSH file transfer, permission denied

Tags: ssh, kali-linux, openssh, file-transfer

I am trying to download a file from a target server for a project. Once I have this file I can gain access to the root however when I try to send the file to my kali machine it doesn't work and says connection refused. I've tried changing my network to not be connected to the victims network but that didn't work either. So I am out of options on what to do. I have included the screenshot of the error i get and am happy to add any necessary screenshots.

[image: Permission denied]
[image: SSH]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am on a tight deadline. Thanks in advance.

I have been told i might need to configure the SSH service on the kali machine but i'm not sure how.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 3):

It's claiming that it cannot write a file to /home. Normal users cannot create files or directories there. I assume you mean some directory beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
joseph@192.168.85.128:/home
```

To be:

```
joseph@192.168.85.128:/home/joseph
```

Comment: `joseph@192.168.85.128:` is enough. But note the `:`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It is a correct answer (assuming joseph's home directory is /home/joseph).  There are lots of ways to copy a file into the destination users home directory and the one specified in this answer is absolutely a valid method.  For a new user, a simple (:) or (:.) may not be very intuitive, but showing him that the mistake was in specifying just /home rather than /home/<username> offers a more valuable lesson.